TypeError: usb.on is not a function
I am trying to use escpos, and escpos-usb in my nodejs project to print receipt. I always get the error usb.on is not a function when i try to start the my server.js file. Is there any alternative in doing this using Epson TM-T20III printer, or if there's a solution to help me fix this
var escpos = require("escpos");
var USB = require("escpos-usb");
const device = new USB();
var printer = new escpos.Printer(device);

const printReceipt = () => {
  device.open(() => {
    printer
      .font("a")
      .align("CT")
      .style("bu")
      .size(1, 1)
      .text("This is a test print")
      .cut()
      .close();
  });
};

module.exports = {
  printReceipt: printReceipt,
};



There is a issue about the problem open: https://github.com/song940/node-escpos/issues/428

I'm not sure if this helps. But if you look at the example code at escpos npmjs page you will see that after requiring escpos you should set the escpos.USB property to the requried/imported "escpos-usb" library.
So your code should be more like
var escpos = require("escpos");

escpos.USB = require("escpos-usb"); // <===

const device = new escpos.USB();
var printer = new escpos.Printer(device);

const printReceipt = () => {
  device.open(() => {
    printer
      .font("a")
      .align("CT")
      .style("bu")
      .size(1, 1)
      .text("This is a test print")
      .cut()
      .close();
  });
};

module.exports = {
  printReceipt: printReceipt,
};

I must admit I have not tested it. But it's possible that the library expects the USB property on the escpos object to be filled with the escpos-usb library.
I hope this helps you.

I’ve found out why, I had to install zadic drivers so that the escpos library can have access to the printer through usb. And also commented out the usb.on() function in escpos-usb library and now it’s all good .
